# Can I cut matrix $W$ in the fraction $\frac{W}{WH}$ when $WH$ is matrix multiplication?

Tags: matrices, fractions

$W_{ik}$ is matrix with $i$ rows and $k$ columns, $H_{kj}$ has $k$ rows and $j$ columns. $\frac{W_{ik}}{W_{ik}H_{kj}}$ is the element-wise division of matrix  but $W_{ik}H_{kj}$ is matrix multiplication. In this case, can $W_{ik}$ be cut out from the fraction? Why?

Comment: Your "division" is element-wise but matrix multiplication is not, so I doubt it.  Counterexamples must be all over the place.

Comment: Also, your division makes no sense unless $j=k$.  How would you element-wise divide matrices of two different dimensions?

Comment: For my last comment, it also doesn't make any sense if $WH$ contains any zeros at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume all the stars align so that all parts of this are defined, the answer is still no.  Let $W$ be the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix and let $H= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.  Then $WH=H$ and $\frac{W}{WH}= W$, the identity matrix. You want this to be $\frac{1}{H}$ which I can only assume you wish to interpret as $H^{-1}$.  However, $H^{-1}$ is not the identity matrix. Even worse, $H^{-1}$ doesn't even exist.

If, instead, you wish to interpret cancellation as $\frac{W}{WH}= \frac{I}{H}$ then $W = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $H$
as above give a counterexample.